# Passing query parameters to query statement in mapserver

Tags: php, gis, openlayers, mapserver

I am using mapserver and openlayers to create a GIS.

I am using a php mapscript and would like to pass the parameters for a query from a html form such that only the polygon(s) that satisfy the query are highlighted in a WFS layer.

I am a newbie with mapserver, openlayers and novice at php, so need help in trying to accomplish the above.

I see the following at the top of my php mapscript:

```
$request = ms_newowsrequestobj();

foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v)  
 {$request->setParameter($k, $v);}
```

which I'm guessing I can use to pass some variables on the url.  Since I'm using a form it'll be `$_POST` instead... Correct?

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I use the above code to pass the parameters from a html form to the mapscript
2. How do I then pass these to the query statement?

Hope what I'm asking makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier (and a better design) to stay away from MapScript and use the GetFeature capabilities of WFS directly.

You can pass in a filter to the WFS layer (see http://mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html), and it can return the feature and attributes that correspond to your query.

Make sure your WFS is configured correctly - http://mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.html#configuring-your-mapfile-to-serve-wfs-layers